# Collecting data from selected dates from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am retrieving data from mysql database using dates.

I like to select data their dates `are >= today's date and date == "0000-00-00"`.

The date column in the database is `date type`.

In my program, I did as

```
$this->db->where('referenceDate >= ', date("Y-m-d") || 'referenceDate == ', "0000-00-00");
```

Where db is the reference to database and `referenceDate is the column name`.

I don't receive those data, their dates are equal to `"0000-00-00".`

What could be wrong in the format?

Comment: Are you using a framework? It looks like you should be using multiple `where()` calls (typical in an ORM) and it will *AND* the clauses by default.

Comment: @JeremyHarris probably its Codeigniter ;)

Comment: Yes sorry it is Codeigniter

Comment: I am new to Codeigniter, so I have difficulty.

Comment: || isn't a SQL OR. Try ```$this->db->where('referenceDate >= "'. date("Y-m-d") . '" OR referenceDate == "0000-00-00"');```

Comment: _I am new to Codeigniter_ Thats why they go to all the bother of writing a manual

Comment: @SloanThrasher no it doesn't load any data.

Comment: Read this [Documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data) . Codeigniter own  best doc among all other framework.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam thanks.now it works. I did $this->db->where('referenceDate >= ', date("Y-m-d"));
        $this->db->or_where('referenceDate = ', "0000-00-00");

Comment: No issues. Enjoy coding ..